# French translation of "poisedness" and "well-poisedness"

Tags: optimization, interpolation, mathematical-french

I am looking for the French translation of the terms "poisedness" and "well-poisedness" (i.e., "$\Lambda$-poisedness"), related to interpolation theory. These terms are, for example, widely used in the book [Introduction to Derivative-Free Optimization](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/book/10.1137/1.9780898718768) by Conn, Scheinberg, and Vicente (e.g., Definitions 3.1 and 3.6).

Thanks in advance for your kind help.

Comment: [poised](https://context.reverso.net/translation/english-french/poised) in French is "en équilibre"

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you! Do you agree that it is then correct to say that "L'ensemble d'interpolation $Y$ est en $\Lambda$-équilibre"?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.